# Por qué al hacer un echo en PHP me arroja lo que quiero imprimir pero con el '?>' además

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once "bd.php";

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
echo $user;   
?>
```

presenta ejemplo(?>Anderson)
Estoy trabajando con jQuery y pasando por Ajax a través de JSON los datos por si acaso

Comment: ¿Te has fijado bien que antes de llamar al código no tengas algún ```?>``` de más? Por ejemplo, en tu archivo **bd.php** podría estar, revisa bien el documento y los archivos que incluyes.

Comment: Gracias, ese era el error. No le prestaba tanta atención puesto que nunca me paso algo así y ahora ya me presenta correctamente la información, gracias bro.